# Weird Behavior of __new__

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-methods

I have encountered a peculiar behavior with the `__new__` method in Python and would like some clarification on its functionality in different scenarios. Let me illustrate with two unrelated classes, `A` and `B`, and provide the initial code:

```py
class A:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(B)

    def __init__(self, param):
        print(param)


class B:
    def __init__(self, param):
        print(param)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(1)
```

In this case, no output is generated, and neither `A`'s `__init__` nor `B`'s `__init__` is called.

However, when I modify the code to make B a child of A:

```py
......
class B(A):
......
```

Suddenly, `B`'s `__init__` is invoked, and it prints 1.

I am seeking clarification on how this behavior is occurring. In the first case, if I want to invoke `B`'s `__init__` explicitly, I find myself resorting to the following modification:

```py
class A:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super().__new__(B)
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj
```

Can someone explain why the initial code behaves as it does and why making `B` a child of `A` alters the behavior? Additionally, how does the modified code explicitly calling `B`'s `__init__` achieve the desired outcome and not without it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR `super().__new__(B)` is not the same as `B()`.

---

As @jonsharpe pointed out in a comment, `__init__` is only called when an instance of `cls` is returned. But this implicit call to `__init__` is handled* by `type.__call__`, not the call to `__new__` itself before it returns.

For example, you can imagine `type.__call__` is implemented as something like

```
def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    if isinstance(obj, cls):
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    return obj
```

So when you call `A(1)` in the first case, this translates to `A.__call__(1)`, which gets implemented as `type.__call__(A, 1)`.

Inside `__call__`, `cls` is bound to `A`, so the first line is equivalent to

```
obj = A.__new__(A, 1)
```

Inside `A.__new__`, you don't pass `cls` as the first argument to `super().new`, but `B`, so `obj` gets assigned an instance of `B`. That object is not an instance of `A`, so `obj.__init__` never gets called, and then the instance is returned.

When you make `B` a subclass of `A`, now `obj` *is* an instance of `A`, so `obj.__init__` gets called.

---

* I *believe* this to be the case; everything I've ever tried is consistent with this model, but I haven't delved deeply enough into CPython to confirm.

For example, if you change `A`'s metaclass to

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

then `B.__init__` fails to be called, even when `B` is a subclass of `A`.

The sentence in the documentation,

> If `__new__()` is invoked during object construction and it returns an
> instance of `cls`, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be
> invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where `self` is the new instance and
> the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to the object
> constructor.

is vague about what exactly "during object construction" means and who is invoking `__init__`. My understanding of `type.__call__` conforms to this, but alternate implementations may be allowed. That would seem to make defining any `__call__` method in a custom metaclass that doesn't return `super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)` a dicey proposition.